# Preventing blocks form gravitating to player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

I'm currently playing with the Hexxit mod pack and the blocks/items are gravitating to me and when my inventory is full, they will orbit around my FOV. I'm not sure if this is desired behaviour, but it's really wrecking my game experience when I have a full inventory and I have 20+ items floating around my FOV, preventing me from seeing anything.

Is there a way to turn off this "feature"?

Here are a couple screenshots of the swarming blocks in action:

[image: Multiple log blocks are clipping through the player camera's angle]

[image: Multiple log blocks are completely obscuring the player's view of the world]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are wearing a Meteoric Helmet, which has the magnetized enchantment on it, blocks will orbit you all the time unless there is space in your inventory, or you take off the helmet.

Answer (score 2):

You're wearing something with the "magnetization" enchantment, or you're wearing Meteoric armor. Both those things will make items swarm you and fog your vision. When your inventory is clear, its a very useful enchantment!